# Checking on PDE problem, done correctly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'd have posted the equation itself in the headline but this seemed simpler.

OK, a PDE: $$a\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + b \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = u$$

So, I'll set up a couple of equations thus: $r = m_{11}x + m_{12}t$ and $s = m_{12}x + m_{22}t$. (We have a nice matrix of m here if we want).

partially differentiating both:$$ \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}= m_{11},\frac{\partial r}{\partial t}= m_{12}, \frac{\partial s}{\partial x}= m_{21}, \frac{\partial s}{\partial t}= m_{22} $$
and plugging them back into the original PDE we get: $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial t}= m_{12} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+ m_{22}\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} $$ and $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\frac{\partial s}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}= m_{21} \frac{\partial u}{\partial s}+ m_{11}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}=u$$
from there I substitute in to the original PDE and got: $$a\left(m_{12} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+ m_{22} \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} \right) + b\left(m_{11} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+ m_{21} \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} \right) \Rightarrow (am_{12}+bm_{11}) \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+ (am_{22}+bm_{21}) \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} =u$$
So I want to get rid of one of the partials. The simplest way to do that is to set one of the coefficients equal to zero. So $am_{12}+bm_{11}=0$. That makes $m_{12}=-b$ and $m_{11}=a$. So my $r$ from above is $r=ax-bt$. 
That leaves me with $$(am_{22}+bm_{21}) \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} =u$$ and I can set $(am_{22}+bm_{21}) = 1$ leaving $m_{22} = \frac{1}{a}$ and $m_{21}=0$. From the equation for $s$ above that leaves us with $s=\frac{1}{a}t$ and we go back to the partials.

Since we set the coefficient of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}$ equal to 1 we are left with $\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}=u$ and that is a simple ODE that reduces to $u=Ce^{-s}$ and 
Since $$u=f(r)e^{-s} = f(ax-bt)e^{-s}= f(ax-bt)e^{-\frac{t}{a}}$$ as our general solution.

So how did I do? We're still int he beginning of the class, and this was one of the problems that is supposed to explore "easy" methods; I know that the method of characteristics would be better. (We're using Asmar's book, BTW, it's a bloody tome but it seems pretty good).

Comment: You are almost correct: $u=f(r)e^s$. In fourth equation there is a leftover "$=u$".

Comment: yeah, re-doing the problem I found it later. But thanks a whole lot. Posting stuff like this that is actually correct builds the confidence, you know?